# Deserialization : several kind of nodes into the same object

Tags: c#, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML document, one of its nodes can be represented like this :

```
<n1 zone="00000" id="0000" />
```

or this :

```
<n2 zone="00000" id="0000" />
```

or this :

```
<n3 zone="00000" id="0000" />
```

In my document I will always have one "n1" node or one "n2" node or one "n3" node. I'd like to deserialize all these fragments into an instance of this class :

```
[Serializable]
public class N
{
    [XmlAttribute("zone")]
    public string Zone { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

But I didn't manage to do that. The documentation suggests to use the XmlChoiceIdentifier attribute in order to accomplish this, but maybe I used it in a wrong way.

Any idea ?

PS : I know I can create three classes : N1, N2 and N3, and map them to my different types of XML fragments. But I'd prefer a cleaner solution.

Comment: Inheritance is coming to mind. Every N* - class inherits from N

Comment: Also XPath comes to mind: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: KyorCode : it's precisely the solution I search to avoid :) But if I don't find an other way I will use inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly understandable read on how to use XmlChoiceIdentifier:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164135.aspx

If you are really having trouble with this, then you could always use an XSL transform to do the mapping first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns> 
  <n1 id="0000" zone="00000"/> 
  <n2 id="0000" zone="00000"/> 
  <n3 id="0000" zone="00000"/> 
</ns>
```

You could use *LINQ to XML*:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(path);
XElement parentNode = document.Element("ns");
var childNodes = parentNode.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.ToString().StartsWith("n")); //this prevent from take elements wich didn't start with n

List<N> list = new List<N>();
foreach (XElement element in childNodes) {
    N n = new N(){ 
        Id = element.Attribute("id").Value, 
        Zone = element.Attribute("zone").Value 
    };

    list.Add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ-To-Xml

```
XDocument x = XDocument.Parse(
           "<root><n1 zone=\"0000\" id=\"0000\"/><n2 zone=\"0001\" id=\"0011\"/><n3 zone=\"0002\" id=\"0022\"/></root>");

var result = from c in x.Element("root").Descendants()
             select new N { Zone = c.Attribute("zone").Value, 
                            Id = c.Attribute("id").Value };
```

It's not using a serializer, which I think you are aiming for but it's a way forward.